# File Read Access outside Docker container in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, docker, .net-core

I have an Dotnet application deployed as docker container which needs to access certain text files(json , lite db etc) which is outside the docker container hosted in a Linux machine. However the same approach
(path format is like c:\foldername) works fine windows machine.
Currently the files are at the path /root/Deployment/Connector/files/ in Linux file system.

Path set in docker compose yaml file is

FilePath=/root/Deployment/RTSConnector/files/StorageUnit.json
LitedbPath=/root/Deployment/Connector/files/LiteDbTest.db

Initally got It throws error Unhandled exception. "System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException" Could not find a part of the path.
Now getting different error
Unhandled exception. System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/files/LiteDbTest.db' is denied.
---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied

What will be proper way to set a file path and read a file for docker container based in Linux. Could anyone please help out here.

tried setting different paths, placed it in docker folder etc and set the path in yaml file. None of them seem to work.

Yaml file Contents

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  rtsconnetorservice:
    image: rtsconnector:1.0.10
    container_name : RTSConnector
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: RPEdge_RTSConnector/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8180:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes/:/https/
      - /root/Deployment/RTSConnector/files/:/files
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=8180
      - ConnectionDetails:EventHubName=
      - ConnectionDetails:EhubNamespaceConnectionString=Endpoint=
      - ConnectionDetails:BlobStorageConnectionString=
      - ConnectionDetails:BlobStorageContainerName=
      - sourceEventHub:ConsumerGroup=
      - TokenProvider:type=
      - Target:ApiURL=
      - Target:ServiceCompany=
      - DefaultTimeoutStatus=10
      - TelemetryTimeoutStatus=10
      - EventTimeoutStatus=10
      - InactiveTimeoutStatus=1
      - HeaderInterval=10
      - FilePath=/files/CurveUnits.csv
  - LitedbPath=/files/LiteDbTest.db
  - BaseUnitFilePath=/files/StorageUnit.json
  - UnitConversionParametersFilePath=/files/unitconversionparameter.json
```

[ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TzSZ.png)
[Filesinlinux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY5Om.png) [yamlfilepath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQKus.png)

Comment: Did you configured the volumes part in your docker-compose.yml? [docker volumes docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) e.g. `volumes: - ./server/file/system/path/:docker/container/path/`? Would you share your docker-compose.yml contents?

Comment: just this - /var/lib/docker/volumes/:/https/